# can't use [Route("")] on strings while school examples show it does

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I'm working on school tasks and up until now everything worked and made sense.
But right now I'm creating routes using controllers and the example code doesn't work locally.
This is the code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace HelloCoreEmpty.Controllers
{
    [Route("about")]
    public class AboutController
    {
        [Route("")]
        public string Phone()
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

The first `[Route]` works but the latter ones return this error:

> "attribute route is not valid on this declaration type"

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Requesting `http://localhost:5031/about/Address` returns `Country`. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MarkSeemann The entire file is this:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace HelloCoreEmpty.Controllers
{
    [Route("about")]
    public class AboutController
    {
        [Route("")]
        public string Phone()
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }
}
with this in my startup.cs:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76929972/edit) the question with the updated code, and format it so that it's readable.

Comment: the code has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `using` statement. You probably meant to reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
// NOT: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
```

The [RouteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routeattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) from the `Mvc` namespace can be used on both classes and methods, whereas the [RouteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routeattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) from the `Components` namespace can be used only on classes, not methods — which would explain the compiler error you're getting when you try to apply the attribute to methods.